# Defining JSON/Object type in graphql-tag

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-tag

I'm kinda new to Apollo gql, just wondering if anyone know if its possible to define Object class in graphql-tag?

```js
export const CREATE_STYLE = gql`
  mutation styleCreate(
    $formID: String!
    $fontFamily: Object //how do you define object/JSON object?
  ) {
    styleCreate(
      formID: $formID
      fontFamily: $fontFamily

    ) {
      styleID

    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if the input type is an object I would recommend to define that on the server as a [input type](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/).

In my setup I'm using:

```
export const createUser = gql`
    mutation createUser($user: UserCreate) {
        create(input: $user) {
            name
            email
        }
    }
```

where "UserCreate" is an interface that looks like:

```
export interface UserCreate {
  // The user name.
  name: string,
  // The user email address.
  email: string,
};
```

You can manually create the interface, but I would suggest to use [apollo codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen) that gives you all the input types you need.